# The date and time takes the timezone of the server where it is hosted rather then where the server is currently used in particular location

Tags: mysql

Suppose I am located in India and my Mysql database server is stored in the Oregon server.So when i am trying to track **datetime** (**i.e. now()**) whenever i perform Insert or update  operation of the data in the table .It always take the time zone of the Oregon server
Can i use the system timezone where my Mysql server is being hosted?

Presently I am using  a function whenever i use to display datetime on front-end

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `FnTimeZone`(P_date datetime) RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
declare returnDate varchar(100);

 Select convert_tz(P_date,'+00:00','+00:00') into returnDate;

RETURN returnDate;
END
```

Can you please help me find better solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can configure the timezone mysql uses. Mysql documentation on [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html) lists all these options for you:

> - The system time zone. When the server starts, it attempts to determine the time zone of the host machine and uses it to set the
>     system_time_zone system variable. The value does not change
>     thereafter.
>
> You can set the system time zone for MySQL Server at startup with the --timezone=timezone_name option to mysqld_safe. You can also set
>   it by setting the TZ environment variable before you start mysqld. The
>   permissible values for --timezone or TZ are system dependent. Consult
>   your operating system documentation to see what values are acceptable.
>
> - The server's current time zone. The global time_zone system variable indicates the time zone the server currently is operating in.
>     The initial value for time_zone is 'SYSTEM', which indicates that the
>     server time zone is the same as the system time zone.
>
> The initial global server time zone value can be specified explicitly at startup with the --default-time-zone=timezone option on
>   the command line, or you can use the following line in an option file:
>
> ```
> default-time-zone='timezone'
> ```
>
> If you have the SUPER privilege, you can set the global server time zone value at runtime with this statement:
>
> ```
> mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;
> ```
>
> - Per-connection time zones. Each client that connects has its own time zone setting, given by the session time_zone variable. Initially,
>     the session variable takes its value from the global time_zone
>     variable, but the client can change its own time zone with this
>     statement:
>
>   ```
>   mysql> SET time_zone = timezone;
>   ```